# TCP Socket Connection = null when trying to send TCP message

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I'm making an Android App that is trying to establish a TCP Connection and outputstream with kotlin Jetpack Compose through a socket by using a function and then send a message using another function inside a same class that saves the socket, input and output stream.

The problem is that I managed to connect the TCPSocket to the designated IP and Port, but when I try to use the established socket using the function to send TCP messages it says the socket and outputstream is null. I am confused as to why this happens

Below is what my codes currently looks like:

```
class TCPHandler {
    private var socket: Socket? = null
    private var messageBytes: ByteArray? = null
    private var output: OutputStream? = null
    private var savedIpAdd = ""
    private var savedportNo = 0
    suspend fun connectToDevice(ipAddress: String, port: Int) {
        savedIpAdd = ipAddress
        savedportNo = port
        while (true){
            try {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    socket = Socket(ipAddress, port)
                    output = socket?.getOutputStream()
                    if (socket?.isConnected == true) {
                        Log.d("TCPdebug", "connected")
                        Log.d("TCPdebug", "$output")
                    } else if (socket == null) {
                        Log.d("TCPdebug", "TCP null")
                        Log.d("TCPdebug", "$output")
                    } else {
                        Log.d("TCPdebug", "Not Connect")
                        Log.d("TCPdebug", "$output")
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e("MyApp", "An error occurred: ${e.message}")
                e.printStackTrace()
                delay(5000)
                socket?.close()
            }
        }
    }

    fun checkConnect(){
        Log.d("myTCP", "${socket?.isConnected}")
        Log.d("myTCP", "$output")
    }

    suspend fun processData(data: String) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            socket!!.close()
            Log.d("myTCP", "${socket?.isConnected}")
            Log.d("myTCP", "$output")
            if(socket != null && output != null){
                messageBytes = hexStringToBytes(data)
                output?.write(messageBytes)
                output?.flush()
            }else{
                socket?.close()
                socket = Socket(savedIpAdd, savedportNo)
                messageBytes = hexStringToBytes(data)
                output?.write(messageBytes)
                output?.flush()
            }
        }
    }

    fun closeConnection() {
        output?.close()
        socket?.close()
    }
}
```

I used a viewModel for the composables to invoke the functions inside the TCPHandler class

```
class AppManagerViewModel : ViewModel() {
    
    private val tcpClient = TCPHandler()

    fun connectToDevice(serverAddress: String, port: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            tcpClient.connectToDevice(deviceAddress, port)
        }
    }

    fun sendData(data: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            tcpClient.processData(data)
        }
    }

    fun checkConnection(){
        tcpClient.checkConnect()
    }

    fun closeConnection() {
        tcpClient.closeConnection()
    }

}
```

And I tried to invoke the connectToDevice function inside a composable that handles loading screen, which then navigate to another screen. After the new screen finishes getting input, it will move back to loading screen and invoke the sendData function.

Then as I've said I managed to get establish tcp connection socket but when I checked it again using a logger I put at the start of processData function it says the socket is null... Any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed an issue in the "processData" function that might be related to the socket and output stream becoming null. It seems that when you attempt to use them in this function, they may have been closed, resulting in null references.

In the "processData" function, you are explicitly closing the socket with the line `socket!!.close()`. Once the socket is closed, it can't be used anymore as well as its associated output stream. This might be the reason why they are null when you try to use them later.

To fix this issue, you could consider handling socket closure more gracefully. Perhaps you could check if the socket is open before closing it and reopen it if necessary. Example of how "processData" function could look like:

```
suspend fun processData(data: String) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        if (socket != null && output != null) {
            try {
                messageBytes = hexStringToBytes(data)
                output?.write(messageBytes)
                output?.flush()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                // Handle the exception, e.g., reconnect or log an error
                Log.e("MyApp", "An error occurred: ${e.message}")
            }
        } else {
            // Reconnect if the socket or output stream is null
            socket?.close()
            socket = Socket(savedIpAdd, savedportNo)
            output = socket?.getOutputStream()
            messageBytes = hexStringToBytes(data)
            output?.write(messageBytes)
            output?.flush()
        }
    }
}
```

Be cautious about multiple threads potentially modifying the socket and output stream. Synchronize access to these variables if they are accessed by multiple threads.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and advice. I managed to identify my main source of trouble (which is actually initialization of multiple viewModel instances of which I used to run the network functions thinking it was the same viewModel all along), but I also think the problems you pointed are valid as well, so I will accommodate my code to your comments as well.